# my jboss is running but not found in my web

Tags: html, http

> HTTP Status 404
>
> Blockquote

type Status report

**message**

description The requested resource (/webname) is not available.

> JBoss Web/7.0.13.Final

why this error is shown?

Answer (score 0):

The file you have requested does not exist on the server.
You should check if:
1) The URL is correct
2) The file exists on the server